Would a 24 V/20 A PSU damage an Arduino Mega 2560?
I am planning to make my first printer which is a Prusa i3 MK2 clone and I want to use a 24 V/20 A PSU so that I can do upgrades in the future and I am wondering if there will be problems of using a 24 V/20 A PSU on an Arduino Mega 2560 with a RAMPS 1.6 shield?

The amperage doesn't matter, but a 24 V is over the specs of the original Arduino Mega 2560 rev3. The limits are 6-20 V according to the specs.
I would like to point out that for a new build you should not use an Arduino Mega 2560 and a RAMPS shield anymore, these are pretty outdated (understatement). There are more modern all in one solutions with more modern microprocessors (namely 32-bit instead of the 8-bit of the Mega 2560).

So what mainboard would you recommend?

That depends on how much steppers you need. You can Google it, use 32 bit 3D printer controller board. I usually get my parts from typical online websites.

FWIW, there is (or was - quite a few years ago, I don't know if it still exists) an Arduino Mega 2560 clone, called the Taurino, that can handle 24 V (12 V up to 35 V, to be precise). The Taurino took its power from the RAMPS board, rather than the usual practice of supplying the Mega board directly.
There was also the Eruduino, and there may be other models now available.
IIRC, the Taurino was useful for handling 24 V heatbeds. Other benefits of using 24 volts over 12 volts include, basically, less (half) current, thinner wires (or less likely to burn out the existing wires), less stress on connectors (where most fires start).
I even made some (really) rough notes about it, at the time, and the required modifications to RAMPS boards, here: Double the volts... double the fun!
The modifications required were two fold:

Replace F2, 11 amp polyfuse (PTC), MF-R1100 which is only rated to 16 V, with wire, and use inline 24 V fuses on wires to heated bed. Note that F1, the MF-R500 (5A) PTC fuse, may be left as it is rated to 30 V
Capacitors under the stepper drives should be 35 V rated, not 16 V which cheaper boards may use.


That said, 0scar is correct with his note about the Mega being outdated, although the Mega/Taurino would probably be OK for a basic DIY printer.

There's a way to allow you to use your 24V 20A PSU.
Chinese manufacturers are making 0-30V buck converters that can handle several amperes in great quantities and at a very low cost. Just buy one of these. You can adjust the voltage and the current limit with a potentiometer. Set the voltage to something lower so your Arduino can handle it, and set the current limit to let's say 2 amperes so the buck converter won't overheat even if maximum current is taken. Note that the specs of the Chinese buck converters are way overrated, they can't handle the advertised current. As long as you take only an amp or two, it doesn't matter, though.
